# iOS Crash - Asynchronous UIImageView setImage EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, crash, uiimageview

I did not experience any crashing in testing, but I've gotten a few crash reports from iTunesConnect that look like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x45d319f8
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a6595be objc_msgSend + 30
1   UIKit                           0x34796e30 -[UIImageView setImage:] + 116
2   My App                      0x000c40b2 -[AsyncImageView setImage:] (AsyncImageView.m:224)
3   My App                      0x000c3950 __47-[AsyncImageView loadImageWithURL:animated:]_block_invoke_2 (AsyncImageView.m:147)
```

AsyncImageView is a typical UIImageView subclass that loads images asynchronously from a URL.

Here is the asset loading code with the offending line number indicated:

```
- (void)loadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url animated:(BOOL)animated {

    if (url == nil) {
        [self setImage:nil];
        return;
    }

    self.imageAsset = [[Asset alloc] init];
    self.imageAsset.assetURL = url;

    AssetRequest *request = [[AssetRequest alloc] init];
    request.assetURL = url;

    __weak AsyncImageView *weakSelf = self;
    self.assetLoader = [AssetLoader AssetLoaderWithRequest:request
                                                 completion:^(Asset *asset){
                                                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                                    if (weakSelf.imageAsset.assetURL == asset.assetURL) {

                                                             weakSelf.imageAsset = asset;

                                                             if (animated) {
                                                                 CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
                                                                 transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
                                                                 transition.duration = 0.20;
                                                                 [weakSelf.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
                                                             }

                                                            [weakSelf setImage:weakSelf.imageAsset.assetImage]; //THIS IS LINE 147


                                                             [weakSelf setDisplayLoadingIndicator:NO];
                                                             [weakSelf stopAnimating];
                                                    }

                                                    });
                                                 }
                                                     error:^(NSError *err){

                                                         if (weakSelf.failedToLoad)
                                                             weakSelf.failedToLoad(url);

                                                     }];

    [self.assetLoader load];
}
```

And here is where is sets the image, with the offending line number indicated:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {

        if (image) {
            [super setImage:image]; //THIS IS LINE 224
            [self hidePlaceholderView];

            if (self.imageLoadedBlock)
                self.imageLoadedBlock();
        }
        else {
            [self showPlaceholderView];
        }

    }
```

The crash report indicates that the crash occurs when setting the image. Is there any obvious reason why this might happen? Or any further error checking I can do (I'm already checking that image isn't null)? And again, this doesn't happen all the time, only once in a while.

Comment: And yet it seems like the image is not actually an image- maybe it's null/nil or corrupted.

Comment: Better yet, try SDWebImage.

Comment: Does it crash *without* the nil checking in setImage as well? This looks fishy to me, especially as it disables nil'ing (i.e.: removing) the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using a walk around for retain cycle:

```
    __weak AsyncImageView *weakSelf = self;
```

With that approach it's not retained by a block - so if someone leaves fast enough before block is executed - selfBlock gets deallocated.

The best is to cancel all operations on dealloc or at least set completion block to "nil".

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [self.assetLoader cancelAllOperations]; //of course you need to implement that
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I think you will be able to reproduce that if you stress test your app and play with it on edge connection and leave a view really quickly before response comes.

Another simpler solution is to not keep "AssetLoader" as property and remote this __block variable letting block to retain "self". But it may lead to unexpected behavior when view is not on screen and will gets updated.

Comment: I tried using an Edge connection but couldn't get it to crash. Please see my posted answer and see if you have any thoughts.

Comment: Could I just set self.assetLoader = nil in the dealloc method?

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the SDWebImage source code and they do something like this when the asset loader completes:

```
if (!weakSelf) {
   return;
}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   if (weakSelf.imageAsset.assetURL == asset.assetURL) {
      weakSelf.imageAsset = asset;
      [weakSelf setImage:weakSelf.imageAsset.assetImage];
       ...
    }                                                         
 });
```

So basically if weakSelf no longer exists don't do anything. Seems a little weird to ask itself if it still exists but would this fix the problem?

Comment: If there is a problem of deallocating "weakSelf" it won't help you - it's a pointer at it will point anyways for the same memory - just object is not there. It will just crash on if(!weakSelf) instead of later.